# API to list applications by language

Tags: android, google-play

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.mobile&hl=en

Given a package name (say com.github.mobile) is there a way to find the following information via API calls.

```
a. Is there a way to find out if its a valid app available in Play Store.
b. Is there a way to find out how many languages its available for (e.g. hl=en or other regional editions)
```

I don't see an API which will allow a user to fetch this information so far, are there any undocumented API(s)

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen api for checking the package name on play store
 But if you want to check it you browse this URL by appending your package name

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

Comment: I have already used the above approach, I am just looking for a better API to do some of this.